# A matrix identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Suppose $A=(a_{jk})_{j,k=1}^n$ is a symmetric complex valued matrix, that is to say, $a_{jk}=a_{kj}$ for all $j,k=1,\dotsc,n$. Suppose that given any two **linearly independent** vectors $\alpha=(\alpha^j)_{j=1}^n, \beta=(\beta^j)_{j=1}^n \in \mathbb C^n$ that satisfy $$\sum_{j=1}^n(\alpha^j)^2=\sum_{j=1}^n(\beta^j)^2 =0,$$
there holds
$$ A(\alpha,\beta)=0.$$
Does it follow that $A=0$?

Comment: What does $A(\alpha, \beta)$ mean?  Is it the same as $\alpha^{\mathsf T}A\beta$?

Comment: Also, whatever $A(\alpha, \beta)$ means, this is false for $n = 1$, since the hypothesis is vacuously satisfied.

Comment: Yes $n$ must exceed one of course. Also $A(x,y)=x^T Ay$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n = 1$, the conclusion that $A = 0$ trivially fails, as noted in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383252/a-matrix-identity#comment974839_383252).

For $n = 2$, the conclusion that $A = 0$ seems also to fail.  We have that any vector $(v_1, v_2)$ of ‘norm’ $v_1^2 + v_2^2 = 0$ is a multiple of $(1, i)$ where $i^2 = -1$, so that, up to changing which square root of $-1$ we call $i$, we have that $\alpha = \alpha^1(1, i)$ and $\beta = \beta^1(1, -i)$.  Then
$$
\alpha^{\mathsf T}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\beta
= \alpha^1\beta^1\begin{pmatrix} 1 & i \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ - i \end{pmatrix} = 0.
$$

Comment: Just wanted to remark that the claim turns out to be true when $n\geq 3$.

Comment: @Ali, in [that](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383252/a-matrix-identity/383253#comment976660_383253) case, it might be a good idea for you to post the proof as an answer and accept that answer instead.